# Using StatusBar in Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, .net, windows, universal

I'm trying to retrieve the StatusBar object from within the view constructor using the following code:
`bool mobile = Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.Phone.PhoneContract",1,0);
if(mobile) {
    var statusbar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
}`

Using Visual Studio Community 2015, I get the following errors:
`Error  CS0731  The type forwarder for type 'Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar' in assembly 'Windows' causes a cycle
Error   CS1069  The type name 'StatusBar' could not be found in the namespace 'Windows.UI.ViewManagement'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.`

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.viewmanagement.statusbar.aspx), this class should be present. I even added a dependency to Package.appxmanifest for the Mobile device family and still nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should add Microsoft Mobile Extension SDK

[image]